# Passing data between TableViewControllers.using didSelect and navigationController without storyboard in Swift 3

Tags: ios, tableview, swift3, uitableview

I know how to pass data from a UITableViewController to another ViewController. *Both of controllers are `UITableViewController`.

For example:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let viewcontroller = NextViewController()
    viewcontroller.someText = "Any text"
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewcontroller, animated: true)
}
```

What this does is when I select a cell in the TableViewController, in next view controller, for example a `UILabel`, say myLabel, is set and a string variable is prepared as someText. And set like `self.myLabel.text = someText`. And when a row is selected, then in the second view controller, "Any text" will be displayed.

However, this is not what I want to use. By which I mean, my goal I am trying to achieve is:

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

//In this case, the next view controller is UITableView.
let viewcontroller = NextViewController()

// I want a selected cell to lead to contain an array of String, 
//so that next view controller will hold multiple cells.
// which are only unique to each cell in first TableViewController. 

viewcontroller.someArray = array????
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewcontroller, animated: true)
}
```

**Update**

**In my SecondTableViewCOntroller**

There is a nvaigationBar and cells are produced by adding text by a `UITextField` inside UIAlertAction. These data is saved with UserDefaults.standfard with "table2". Also, there is a variable, an array of String set;

```
  //Gloabally Declared
  var myArray = [String](); 
  var array = [String]();

  //This function is displayed in didViewLoad()
  func data(){
    if let myArray = savedata.stringArray(forKey: KEY) {
       array = myArray
    }
 }


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    for object in cell.contentView.subviews
    {
        object.removeFromSuperview();
    }
    let getData = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey:"table2")

    cell.textLabel?.text = getData[indexPath.row] 
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: familyFont, size: 19)
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 19)
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
    cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center

    return cell
}
```

**In my `FirstTableViewController`:**

In this `tableViewController`, cells are populated by adding text in a `UITextField` placed on the `navigationBar`. Then I want the selected cell to hold cells created in `SecondTableViewController` by adding text by a `UITextField`insdie `UIAlertAction`.  These data is saved with UserDefaults.standfard with "table1"

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    for object in cell.contentView.subviews
    {
        object.removeFromSuperview();
    }
    let getData = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey:"table1")

    cell.textLabel?.myArray = getData[indexPath.row] 

    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: familyFont, size: 19)
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 19)
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
    cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center

    return cell
}
```

I do not know how to implement code that achieves this. I have researched posts and googled so hard, but what I could find was only about passing data between a view controller and table view controller, but in my case, it is about passing data between TableView to TableView. So this might help others who have the same trouble too.

This has bugged me for a long time. Please help me...

Thanks!

Comment: If that is not a viewController, How can you push that?? If it is normal table view/ custom view you have to add that as a subview. And for the issue of passing data you can customize the init method.

Comment: Can you show the `cellForRowAt indexPath` method, so that will clear what you want to pass as array.

Comment: updated, please check.

Comment: @Janmenjaya How do you pass data by init??? Could you provide me any code?

Comment: @Ryo, Check my answer to see how to customize init method of View to pass data.

Answer (score 0):

You are close, and the concept stays the same.  In this case you would pass the array of Strings that you want to use in the next tableView and use that array as the datasource for the second table so you would have:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = NewTableViewController()
    vc.dataSourceArray = array
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Then in your new tableView set your numberForSections(), numForRows(), and cellForIndexPath() based on your dataSourceArray.  This will populate the new tableView with the passed data.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, I think you are trying to send your data to custom view class not to viewController class.

So I suggested to customize the init method of view class.

**NB : The code I have shown below is written in Swift 2.1.**

Here in the example I have taken a `UIView` and design table view inside that view. I passed the data from the view controller and showing the list of data as dropdown list.

**Code :**

**In the Custom View**

```
init(frame: CGRect, arrData: NSArray) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    arrListData = NSMutableArray(array: arrData)

    //In this method I have designed the table view 
    designListView();
}
```

**In the ViewController :**

```
func ListButtonClicked()
{
    let arr = ["Asia", "Europe", "Africa", "North America", "South America", "Australia", "Antarctica"]

    dropDownlist = DropdownView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height), arrData: arr);
    dropDownlist.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor();
    self.view.addSubview(dropDownlist)
}
```

Here I have mentioned part of code, but for your convenience I am adding the output screen so that you can check whether this fulfil your requirement or not.

My output:

[image]